# How can I display the print option for a pdf stream returned by a wcf service?

Tags: javascript, pdf-generation

My wcf service create a pdf stream and return it, through the ajax call I'm properly handling the display in a new window and the download of the pdf file.

There is an option that I need to add which is directly show the print options for the document.
I tried using iframe but the document preview doesn't properly show the pdf as expected.

This code works fine for download:

```
    var blob = b64toBlob(base64PDF, { type: 'application/pdf;' });
    var link = document.createElement('a');
    link.href = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
    link.download = f + ".pdf";
    link.click();
```

This is the code I'm trying to use to send the document to the printer:

```
var blob = b64toBlob(base64PDF, { type: 'application/pdf;' });
var iUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
iUrl.download = f + ".pdf";
printPdf(iUrl);

function printPdf(url) {

    var iframe = this._printIframe;
    if (!this._printIframe) {
        iframe = this._printIframe = document.createElement('iframe');
        document.body.appendChild(iframe);

        iframe.style.display = 'none';
        iframe.onload = function () {
            setTimeout(function () {
                iframe.focus();
                iframe.contentWindow.print();
            }, 1);
        };
    }

    iframe.src = url;
}
```

I also tried few other approaches that are not any better.

```
var blob = b64toBlob(base64PDF, { type: 'application/pdf;' });
var iUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = iUrl;
iframe.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print()
    }, 1);
};

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

This code open the printing window but the document looks wrong, I basically get This:
[Pdf print preview](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VpvP5.png)

As my pdf stream is a base64 string I thought I can create the blob directly as base 64, so I tried this code

```
var blob = new Blob([base64PDF], { type: 'application/pdf;base64,' })
var iUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(blob);
var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
iframe.style.display = 'none';
iframe.src = iUrl;
iframe.onload = function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        iframe.focus();
        iframe.contentWindow.print()
    }, 1);
};

document.body.appendChild(iframe);
```

Now nothing happen and I don't get the print preview page but in the console I get "Resource interpreted as Document but transferred with MIME type application/pdf:"